# Javascript countdown for specific time and date

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I am using a jQuery plugin to put the countdown timer in my webpage. Currently the code that controls what the timer displays is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(3600 * 24 * 3, {
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        countdown: true
    });
</script>
```

The JS for the plugin can be viewed here: https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/blob/master/js/flipclock/flipclock.js

The example page of the code in use can be seen here:
http://flipclockjs.com/faces/daily-counter

Currently the timer is a countdown for 3 days which resets everytime the page is refreshed. I want to use a custom time for the countdown timer which will be absolute(wont reset with page refresh). I want the date to be September 30, 2013 at 12:00pm PST   (US West - California Time Zone).

Is there anyway to do this using Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: you have rights to write php code?

Comment: nope.. javascript only

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Get the current time, and note that this will be the time set on the users computer clock, whatever that is set to, and set a certain date, then calculate the difference and use that for the plugin:

```
var date  = new Date(Date.UTC(2013, 8, 30, 12, 0, 0));
var now   = new Date();
var diff  = date.getTime()/1000 - now.getTime()/1000;

var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true
});
```

For accurate times I would reccoment using your webserver to output the current time.

Comment: And what does the typeError say ?

Comment: I should probably note that the plugin you're linking to is called ***FlipClock*** and not ***FlipClip*** ?

Comment: yes it is flipclock not flipclip, but unfortunately that doesnt work either as seen on http://www.domainandseo.com/26/index.html.... the normal version is http://www.domainandseo.com/26/index1.html

Comment: @AlexZahir - But on that page there is no `.clock` element, it's called `.countdown` ?

Comment: yes you are right. implemented your code on http://www.domainandseo.com/26/index.html... with the 35 days there is '420' ?.. I mean days have 5 numbers whereas it should have only 2

Comment: @AlexZahir - It's because it doesn't accept millliseconds, but seconds, edited the answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot adeno... thanks for sticking by me throughout all this.. chose your answer as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: @Adeneo Can you provide a fiddle for this? 
I dont know if there's a bug in the Plugin,but the DailCounter Clockface aint working for me.
No errors either.

Comment: add another parameter for milliseconds - e.g.

`var date  = new Date(Date.UTC(2013, 8, 30, 12, 0, 0, 0));`

Answer (score 9):

I'd do it that way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(new Date(2013,8,30).getTime()/1000 - new Date().getTime()/1000, {
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        countdown: true
    });
</script>
```

This counts down till the date Sept, 30 2013... I didn't try it yet so I'm not sure it's working.

Edit: Corrected the date to be new Date(2013,8,30) instead of new Date(2013,9,30) as the month counting starts from 0 not 1.

Comment: this is good, but this actually says "64 days left" but until 30th september there shuould be about '35 days left.' So I'm thinking something should be wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It should be new Date(2013,8,30). Put the month you want - 1 as the counting of months start from 0 not 1. It is probably because it counts the difference from a certain date where the month is January so if you want to represent January, you have to use 0. To represent September, you have to use 8.
I've edited the answer to be the correct one now.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks a lot. I gave ur answer a plus one, but the other answer got the selected answer cuz it also set the default timezone to UTC as requested in the question. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm asssuming the first arg of .FlipClip() is the amount of time until the countdown completes. This time, "t", should be the difference between now and the target time.

```
var t = targetTimeInMs - currentTimeInMs;
```

To get the current time, use the no-arg Date constructor.

```
var currentTimeInMs = new Date().getTime();
```

To get the target time, supply Date with arguments. Here are a few examples from MDN:

```
var today = new Date();
var birthday = new Date("December 17, 1995 03:24:00");
var birthday = new Date(1995,11,17);
var birthday = new Date(1995,11,17,3,24,0);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

I'm not exactly sure if you need to supply milliseconds as the first arg to your .FlipClip() function. Consult the documentation/source for that. Then use the appropriate method of the Date object to get the required unit (seconds? minutes? hours? and use date.getSeconds(), getHours(), etc, see MDN.)