# FlipClock countdown timer showing wrong for the given date and time

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I am using jQuery [FlipClock](http://flipclockjs.com/) to show a countdown timer for a given date time.
So to show countdown timer with given date and time in FlipClock I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434166/javascript-countdown-for-specific-time-and-date) link.
 In my case the end date is

```
8th December 2015, 12:0:0
```

So as per the link above I made my code like this

```
 var date  = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 12, 8, 12, 0, 0));
            var now = new Date();
            var diff  = date.getTime()/1000 - now.getTime()/1000;
            var clock;
            clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
                clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
                autoStart: false,
                callbacks: {
                    stop: function() {
                        $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
                    }
                }
            });
            clock.setTime(diff);
            clock.setCountdown(true);
            clock.start();

<div class="clock"></div>
```

But its showing countdown dates in wrong. So may I know why I am getting this error? How to solve the issue? Any suggestion or advice is really appreciable. Thanks

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/cqgw1mb3/6/) link

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the month is zero based, in `Date.UTC`

```
 var date  = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 11, 8, 12, 0, 0)); //11 for Dec
```

See the documentation (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp)

> month : Required. An integer representing the month Expected values are
>   0-11, but other values are allowed:
>
> -1 will result in the last month of the previous year
>
> 12 will result in the first month of the next year
>
> 13 will result in the second of the next year

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/cqgw1mb3/7

Comment: `var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 11, 8, 12, 0, 0));` this line will give u   `8-Dec-2015 12:00:00 (+TimeZone)`